# How to assign hexadecimal value to char variable in plsql

Tags: c, plsql

Below is the piece of code from C, here they are assigning the hexadecimal value to a char variable sKaigyoCode

```
char    sKaigyoCode[512];

sKaigyoCode[0] = 0x0d;
sKaigyoCode[1] = 0x0a;
```

I am trying to do the same thing in PLSQL

```
sKaigyoCode CHAR(512);

sKaigyoCode[0] = 0x0d;
sKaigyoCode[1] = 0x0a;
```

Which shows compile time error

> Error(46,18): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "[" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;
>   Error(46,23): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "X0D" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol "*" was substituted for "X0D" to continue.

Comment: In PLSQL CHAR(512) does not mean "an array of 512 elements of type CHAR", but it's a specific type that you have to use according to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS332)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, `char`, `varchar`, `varchar2`, `nvarchar2`, etc. are not arrays. Also, usually there is no need to use hex values in PL/SQL. But if you need to put special characters into a string variable you can do this:

```
declare
  sKaigyoCode CHAR(512);
begin
  sKaigyoCode := chr(10) || chr(13);
end;
```

And opposite operation - to return a symbol code:

```
declare
  a number;
begin
  a := ascii(substr('Hello, world!', 1, 1));
end;
```